# Counting the articles which don't have a price change in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns: suppliercode, articlecode, price, date, ArticleChanges. All I want is to count the articles where the price didn't change (the result will be on a additional column - ArticleChanges)
For instance:

[image]

For supplier 12345 I will have 1 article from a total of 2 articles which didn't change the price.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to aggregate by suppler and article.  Then, you can compare the minimum and maximum prices:

```
select suppliercode, articlecode
from t
group by suppliercode, articlecode
having min(price) = max(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do as Gordon has suggested and use the 'Having' statement, which can potentially impact performance as it is quite a heavy query, or you could do something like the following:

```
Select * From (
    Select 
        Min(Price) as Minimum, 
        Max(Price) as Maximum, 
        SupplierCode, 
        ArticleCode
    From
        t
    Group by
        SupplierCode,
        ArticleCode) MainQuery
    Where MainQuery.Minimum = MainQuery.Maximum
```

See which one performs better as I'm sure there are cases where either one performs better.